# Why do I get "Incompatible indexer with Series"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two Dataframes with the same structure:

lTable and rTable

I loop through one to update with values from the other:

```
for i,lrow in lTable.iterrows():

    rrows = rTable[rTable.Date == lrow["Date"]]
    if not rrows.empty:

        ref = rrows.head(1)["RefPrice"]
        lTable.loc[i,"RefPrice"] = ref
```

Why do I get ValueError on ".loc" line:

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here change one element `Series` returned after filter rows with `head(1)`:

```
ref = rrows.head(1)["RefPrice"]
```

to scalar by selecting first value by position:

```
ref = rrows["RefPrice"].iat[0]
```

Or one line solution:

```
ref = rrows.head(1)["RefPrice"]    
lTable.loc[i,"RefPrice"] = ref
```

to:

```
lTable.loc[i,"RefPrice"] = rrows["RefPrice"].iat[0]
```

But better/faster should be merge with left join:

```
lTable = lTable.merge(rTable[['Date', "RefPrice"]], on='Date', how='left')
```

Comment: That doesn't address my problem - which is on the .loc line does it?

Comment: @ManInMoon - Yes, there is assigned `ref`, so raised error. If change `ref = rrows["RefPrice"].iat[0]` it should working.